# How can I print the next 3 lines after reading a name from a .txt file?

Tags: java

I'm sure you'll be able to tell, but i'm new to java.
Anyways i'm trying to read the next 3 lines from after a person types in a name to search from a txt file when there is other names and info in the file. The info was put into the txt file from another program that asked the first name, last name, id number, and years of experience and printed them on separate lines. This is what I have so far.

```
System.out.println("Please enter first name of employee.");
  String employeeName = keyboard.nextLine();    

  // Check to see if the name is in the file
  // And for some reason if the name is in it, it says that it's not
  if(fileName.contains(employeeName))
  {
     System.out.println("Sorry, that employee is not in the file.");
  }
  else
  {                
     // Read the last name.
     String lastName = inputFile.nextLine();
     System.out.println(lastName);

     // Read the employee number
     String employeeID = inputFile.nextLine();
     System.out.println(employeeID);

     // Read the years of experience
     String years = inputFile.nextLine();
     System.out.println(years);
  }
```

Comment: You can also use a loop, like `for`.

Comment: You seem to have switched from reading `keyboard` to reading `inputFile`.

Comment: I was trying to think of how to use the for loop, but couldn't think of how to.

Comment: And if I read keyboard, wouldn't it try to read what the person types in, instead of from the .txt file?

Comment: Do you need to keep the data you're reading into `lastName`, `employeeID` and `years` for future use or are they just temporarily storing so that you can output?

Comment: I don't believe so. I'm pretty sure they're just temporary.

Answer (score 0):

you can use .hasNext method to read the lines in a file

here is my pseudo code:

```
else
{

String[] name;
int[] id;
int[] yearsofexp;

while (filename.hasNext()) 
            {
                name = filename.nextLine(); 
                id = filename.nextInt;
                yearsofexp = filename.nextInt();

            }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    create a file "myFile.txt" and save it in the same folder with your code.
```

public class Abebe {
        public static void main(String [] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

```
        Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter first name of employee.");


        String employeeName = keyboard.nextLine();

      File fileName= new File("myFile.txt");  // open the file

        Scanner inputFile= new Scanner(fileName); // read in the file

        if(!inputFile.hasNext(employeeName))  // here you are checking if the name you entered is available in your file
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, that employee is not in the file.");
        }
        else
        {
            // Read the last name.
            String lastName = inputFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println(lastName);

            // Read the employee number
            String employeeID = inputFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println(employeeID);

            // Read the years of experience
            String years = inputFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println(years);
        }
}}
```